# Counting the character 'e'

Tags: java, character

Hi I have to create a method that takes the word message, and counts how many times the character e appears this is what I have but I always get 0. any suggestions?

```
public class run
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


  String message ="message";


  int count=0;
  for(int i=0; i>=message.length()-1;i++)
  {

    char ch = message.charAt(i);
    char e='e';
    if( ch == e)
    {
     count = count +1;

    }

  }

  System.out.println(count);



 }

}
```

Comment: `i>=message.length()-1` Is 0 ever bigger than that?

Comment: If you're feeling cheeky: `count = message.replaceAll("[^e]", "").length()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i>=message.length()-1;i++)
```

This will never enter the loop (except for some short-message edge cases where it will then stay in the loop for quite a while) since you have the comparison sense around the wrong way. You need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
```

And you don't really need those extra variables, this will do fine:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    if (message.charAt(i) == 'e')
        count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another *recursive* method:

```
public int countE(String str) {

    int count = 0;

    if (str.charAt(0) == 'e') 
        count++;

    if (str.length() > 1) {
        count += countE (str.substring(1));
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: And when you pass in a string with lots of `e` characters in it, what do you think will happen in terms of stack frames? A test program I wrote works with a string of 4096 e's but on upping that to 8192, we see `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Recursion is the _wrong_ tool for this job.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually the amount of `e`s would have no relevance,  It would be the length of the message.  I agree that I would not personally use recursion for this problem and also I would avoid parsing `String`s with thousands of `e`s in them.

Answer (score -1):

Heres a recursive solution:

```
public static int countChar (String message, char e)
{
    int charOccurences = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < message.length () ; i++)
    {
        if (message.charAt (i) == e)
        {
            charOccurences++;
            message = message.substring (0, i) + message.substring (i + 1);
            return charOccurences + countChar (message, e); 
        }

    }
    return charOccurences;
}
```

Comment: Why do i get downvotes for everything???? Im trying to help. There are multiple ways to solve the problem...Im just offering another. Why is that deserving of downvotes?

Comment: If this was not using a hybrid of loop and recursive logic, it might have been worth something.

Comment: Don't cry Noob. Fix you problems (remember we are all still learning too) and the downvote may go away.

Comment: Im honestly trying to help. But everything I do seems to get downvotes, even if its a valid answer.

Comment: Noob, it's probably getting downvoted because it uses recursion in a totally unnecessary way. Recursion _does_ have a certain elegance but I don't think this is a suitable problem for it to solve. It's akin to `def add(a,b): if b == 0 return a else return add (a+1,b-1)` :-) In other words, recursion is good if it can reduce the potential solution space quickly (a la binary search). Otherwise, the overhead of function calls (in time and stack space) are likely to be problematic.

Comment: @Noob Have a look at my answer. In your analogy to the linked picture, your method is like also putting balloons on the car.  It still works but...

Comment: ...it makes it more awesome. I dont see the issue.

Comment: @Noob Thats a pity, it means you are not learning.  Why use loop logic and recursive logic.  One or the other would be fine.  As such brainy dude said "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler."